# What does the Web.Config file do in the views folder of a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm having some problems with deploying my application and while troubleshooting, I came across the `Web.Config` file in the `Views` folder. In an attempt to narrow down the possibilities of sources to my problem, I tried to find out the purpose of that `Web.Config` file but can't really find much information.

So basically my questions are:

1. What does the `Web.config` file do in the `Views` folder of a MVC project?
2. Is it required?

In ASP.NET webforms, I believe that to use a separate `web.config` file in a folder, that folder has to be set as a virtual folder in IIS. Is this the case in MVC (i.e. does the `Views` folder need to be configured as a virtual folder)?

Comment: There are no "stupid" questions

Comment: Never be afraid to ask "stupid" questions.  If you don't know the answer then its not "stupid".  Nothing "stupid" about getting a better understanding of something.

Comment: SO is known for dousing users in napalm for asking questions...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No, you do not need to configure a virtual folder because of this extra `web.config` file.

The `web.config` file exists in the `Views` folders to prevent access to your views by any means other than your controller. In the MVC design pattern, controllers are supposed to route requests and return a rendered view to the calling client.

In other words, your view at `www.mydomain.com/MySuperController/AwesomeAction1/SweetPage.aspx` should *not* be directly accessible.

If you peek at the `web.config` file it actually registers the `HttpNotFoundHandler` to all paths and verbs:

```
<add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
```

Or, in IIS 7 it might look like

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" 
    preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
```

Comment: But the generated web.config contains a huge amount of other text - that's all redundant?

Answer (score 8):

It configures the compiler for the views such as importing namespaces and makes the views folder return a 404.

Answer (score 7):

The `web.config` file in the views folder is to do some specialized settings you want to apply to pages inside the view folder.

Like config settings like: connection string / appsettings etc.

But that will be applicable to only that folder and rest of the project will pick up the settings from `web.config` present at the root.

Specially when you use concept of area there will be separate folder for each area containing separate web.cfg file where you can apply separate settings for each area.

Answer (score 6):

That's if you want to override something mentioned in the upper `web.config`, i.e. if you want to customize something within the scope of the `Views` folder.