# what is the purpose of web.config in views folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the web.config file do in the views folder of a MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204341/what-does-the-web-config-file-do-in-the-views-folder-of-a-mvc-project)

in a mvc 3 project i see two web.config files, one at the root level and one within views.

what is the one in the views being used for?

what are some of the use cases for that web.config?