# Custom view engine locations view model parsing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

So I've been tinkering with View locations for an MVC app I'm working on, specifically because I need to be able to use views/routes for a parent site in a child site.

Ultimately I want to be able to serve up views from a different location, say ~/SiteAViews/.. Where ~ is the root of site B, and the views deposited in site ~/SiteAViews/ are views copied in a post build event from SiteA.

Sounds easy with a custom view engine. However, I've done this in a custom view engine (example change below) adding to the locations for the view and master pages. The problem occurs when accessing a URI, and therefore route that is defined in the SiteA dll (referenced in siteB).

```
this.ViewLocationFormats = new string[8]
{
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",

    "~/SiteAViews/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/SiteAViews/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/SiteAViews/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/SiteAViews/Shared/{0}.ascx"
};
```

If I change the view engine, and post build task, to refer to/copy content to ~/views/SiteA/.. rather than ~/SiteAViews/.. it all works great and parses the ViewModel. However, with ~/SiteAViews/.. I receive the following.

> Exception type: HttpParseException Exception message: Could not load
>   type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<'Shared.MyViewModel'>'. at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the information in `web.config` file found in the **Views** folder. In asp.net the configuration for a given folder will be resolved following this hierarchy of `web.config` files:

```
machine.config -> root application web.config -> subdirectory web.config
```

In the case of asp mvc, the web.config file in the **Views** folder will configure the default namespaces to be included when compiling each view into its class and a default handler that prevents the view files from being directly accessed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204341/what-does-the-web-config-file-do-in-the-views-folder-of-a-mvc-project).

As you have created another directory **SiteAViews** in the root of your project (i.e. outside the **Views** folder), you are missing the basic mvc configuration that `~/Views/web.config` provides. You could fix it by copying `~/Views/web.config` into `~/SiteAViews/web.config`. (If you were using Razor you may want to copy the _ViewStart.cshtml file as well)

If you don´t like having to maintain 2 similar config files you will need to create a view folders hierarchy with a common root where you can put the web.config file (and adjust your view engine accordingly):

```
~/ViewLocations/web.config     //common asp mvc views config
~/ViewLocations/Views/         //SiteB views
~/ViewLocations/SiteAViews/    //SiteA views

//In your view engine:
this.ViewLocationFormats = new string[8]
{
    "~/ViewLocations/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/ViewLocations/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/ViewLocations/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/ViewLocations/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",

    "~/ViewLocations/SiteAViews/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/ViewLocations/SiteAViews/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/ViewLocations/SiteAViews/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/ViewLocations/SiteAViews/Shared/{0}.ascx"
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Great answer, which needless to say worked. I copied the web.config in to SiteAViews and all works fine. I'll consider your answer in full though to get the best, rather than quickest solution. I've never looked in to the purpose of the Views/Web.config before, now I know. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers Tim, glad to be of help :)