# ~/Views/Web.config and its content

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a website since zero, and I've used the MVC pattern.

~/Web.config has the assembly references to some DLLs, but what has ~/Views/Web.config? Yes, this file block the access to the controllers and more., but this file is adding namespaces (and more things), for example. Why is this necessary?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication4" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204341/what-does-the-web-config-file-do-in-the-views-folder-of-a-mvc-project

Comment: The namespaces are the namespaces that razor pages have set as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets the base page type:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

Without the above line you would have to set it on each view like this:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

*WebViewPage* has properties like `Html` and `Url` that integrate MVC with Razor.

Comment: Nice!
And what is "<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory..." which is up of pageBaseType?

Comment: @Joe It enables MVC's custom Razor parser, which extends Razor e.g. `@model` directive.