# Razor syntax broken on MVC 5 views VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following problem:

Razor syntax shows errors on view and won't autocomplete in most cases, for example:

```
@model someModel // The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SomeProp) // System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper does not contain a defenition for 'EditorFor'.... same for .Partial and  .OtherExtensions

//This do work:
@Html.CheckBox //.DropDown .Encode .Hidden ect... (The non extended properties of html)
```

What I've tried to far based on similar SO topics:

1. Make sure I have the same webpages / mvc version on the web.config in the main dir. and in the Views dir.
2. Unload the project, delete the .user file, reload project (that helped once though)
3. Rebuild/ clean/ delete the bin files

This is driving me crazy, please help!

added: Using Webpages 3.0.3XXX and MVC 5.2.3XXX

added #2: It seems it happen because the Views directory was separated to another project - don't do it! use the views in the same project as your mvc controllers.

Comment: Did you happen to upgrade to MVC 5 from an older version? If yes, an all inclusive search of the previous version number (like System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.0) will help. I thought I had every .config file checked too, but there were some residual stuff.

Comment: Tnx, I've searched entire solution for web.system.mvc and webpages, it is all 5.2.3.0 and 3.0.0, I did not upgrade from 4, it was a new project MVC5

Comment: @ZivWeissman Did you try adding namespace by `@using` on top of view?

Comment: @User3250 tnx for your input, yes I've tried with the using.

Comment: Nothing seems to have worked since an year :)

Comment: @User3250 yes I gave up on this, I think I know the reason, not the solution though - It was due to separation of MVC controllers and Views on another project.

Comment: question 1 - is it only in this view or all views?  question 2 - If you look at ~/Views/web.config, do you have the following namespace listed: `System.Web.Mvc.Html`?  The web.config in the Views folder will import this namespace for all views under the Views folder.  See the `<namespaces>` element in this question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810936/views-web-config-and-its-content

Comment: I didn't realize this was a year old :)

Answer (score 0):

The MVC architecture always looks for views in the following folders

**~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.[cshtml|vbhtml|aspx|ascx]**

OR

**~/Views/Shared/ActionName.[cshtml|vbhtml|aspx|ascx]**

Secondly, you can specify where to look for as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909594/3503015) article. Though never tried it myself.