# 404 when converting asp.net mvc app to angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

so I have my full asp.net mvc project working which renders perfectly fine.

Then I am trying to convert it to use angular for the UI and web api for the backend.

In the views folder I added an index.html file with this code:

```
<!--
* INSPINIA - Responsive Admin Theme
* Version 2.0
*
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inspinia">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
    <title page-title></title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files -->
    <link href="~/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="loadBefore" href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used in Inspinia theme on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

    <!-- Main view  -->
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- MetsiMenu -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

    <!-- SlimScroll -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Peace JS -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/inspinia.js"></script>

    <!-- Main Angular scripts-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>

    <!--
     You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
     When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
     After your sign up replace the key in the URL below..
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQTpXj82d8UpCi97wzo_nKXL7nYrd4G70"></script>

    <!-- Anglar App Script -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/config.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/translations.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However I get a 404 when I try to browse to /views/index.html

So I suppose MVC restricts in some way to see html files on this folder.
Whats the solution here?

Comment: shame on the -1s without a comment.

Comment: This looks like routing problem in MVC, its not problem with angularjs, try to create static html page and open it, i assume it will return you same 404 error.

Comment: Have you seen the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: MVC pattern means the controller takes requests and renders views. You are trying to bypass that and the Views/web.config prevents that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205076/408747

Comment: With the previous comment's caveat, you [can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24789089/304683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC pattern means the controller takes requests and renders views. You are trying to bypass that and the [Views/web.config prevents that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205076/408747).

You can either

- render your view via the Controller (MVC-style), or  configure a
- section of your app to [serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc)